# How to change grails localhost port?

Tags: grails

I'm using grails 2.0.4. And I want to use port:8090 instead of 8080 for localhost. So need help to change the port to 8090 permanently.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Change `grails.serverURL` in `Config.groovy` from `"http://localhost:8080/${appName}"` to `"http://localhost:8090/${appName}"`.
2. Launch grails with `-Dgrails.server.port.http=8090` on the command line.  Set the `GRAILS_OPTS` environment variable to `-Dgrails.server.port.http=8090` to have it applied automatically.

Comment: from the command line you can also just use -Dserver.port=8090

Comment: for grails 3 you can only use -Dserver.port=8090

Answer (score 136):

This solution adds to the answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/10956283/122457. In Grails 2.x, 
add the following to `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.server.port.http = 8090
```

See http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-97024.html for further details.

Comment: This is the better solution.  Has less moving parts.

Comment: I tried this method and it did not work, is there a specific section in which this should be placed?  I stuck it under the `grails.project.target.level` section, and it appeared to have no effect.

Comment: @TedDelezene this doesn't go under any other section. Did you restart the application after changing the configuration? - Because only that would reload the configuration (and your change of it).

Comment: Yes I did, and it didn't work for me, however now I just start it with the -Dserver.grails.port.http=49494  option.

Answer (score 36):

If you are using Netbeans IDE then set the following -:

Config: -> BuildConfig.groovy: -> grails.server.port.http = 8090
and restart the server.

Without IDE, type in the command prompt -:

```
grails -Dserver.port 8090 run-app
```

or

```
grails -Dserver.port=8090 run-app
```

Comment: Very informative and tells every way to do this. Thanks gautam.

Comment: @Gautam  There was no field like grails.server.port.http in my BuildConfig,  so I manually added it and tried but it gave response like 8080 in use(I was using it to deploy using tomcat).  What could be the problem I have made.   I have put grails.server.port.http = 8090 at the very beginning of BuildConfig

Comment: Try to kill all port of 80 and then try. For linux use '' sudo fuser -n tcp -k 80 '' or  ' lsof -t -i:8080 ' in terminal

Answer (score 21):

For grails 3 you can put this in your ***application.yml***

```
server:
    port: 9999
```

Comment: Or more concisely as `server.port: 9999`.

Comment: or using jvm option -Dserver.port=9999

Comment: Why is this so highly upvoted? The OP asked about grails 2. This answer is entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 12):

command line: `grails run-app -port 8090`

Comment: This did not work for me, still starts on 8080.  Very odd

Comment: This fixed it for me in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.1

Comment: Works for **IDEA 2020.1** with **Grails 3.3.11**. Thanks!

Comment: This simple/easy solution still works well under **IDEA 2022.3.1** with **Grails 5.3.2**: In the *Select Run/Debug Configuration* dropdown, click on *Edit Configurations...*, then change the Grails setting *Command Line* to `run-app -port 8090`

Answer (score 6):

Run the command (Ctrl+Alt+g)

1. Up to grails version 2.x : `run-app -Dserver.port=8090`
2. For grails version 3.x : `run-app --port=8090`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using IntelliJ IDE then

From the application menu click Run >> Edit Configurations... >> VM options: -Dgrails.server.port.http=8180

Answer (score 5):

grails run-app -Dserver.port=8090

***Or use another port number***

In Intellij:
 Ctrl+Alt+G (keyboard Generic);
 Cmd+Alt+G (keyboard Mac)
 and use only:

run-app -Dserver.port=8090

Comment: This did not work for me either, still starts on 8080

Comment: What version of Grails you have?

Comment: Same here, it didn't worked for me. I am on grails 1.3.7 running on Mac OS 13.12.3. I think it is not OS specific issue.

Comment: Check the guide in the section: 2.7 Running an Application... 

http://docs.grails.org/1.3.7/guide/single.html

You can specify a different port by using the server.port argument:

grails -Dserver.port=8090 run-app

Answer (score 3):

Add/Update the value of port from your application.yml (grails-app/conf/application.yml)

```
environments:
   development:
        server:
            port: "8090"
```

Or

```
server:
    port: "8090"
```

Answer (score 1):

Type following in the command line:

```
grails -Dserver.port=8090 run-app
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what IDE you are using. If you are using Netbeans you just right-click on the project name and choose Properties. From the General Settings Category,  you can easily change the server port to whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can run grails app using the following command on the terminal. default running port is 8080.

grails run-app -Dserver.port=9090

This will run the app on port 9090.

Answer (score 0):

For Grails 4 required two settings

```
server:
   port: "8085"
grails:
   serverURL: http://localhost:8085
```

Second one will solve redirection issues

Or only for dev:

```
environments:
    development:
        server:
            port: "8085"
        grails:
            serverURL: http://localhost:8085
```