# Grails 2.4.2 - grails.server.port.http doesn't override default port

Tags: grails

In Grails 2.4.2 I'm having

```
grails.server.port.http = 18080
grails.server.port.https = 18443
```

in `BuildConfig.groovy`.

Nonetheless `grails run-app` starts on the default ports.

Do we have another approach for it?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955899/how-to-change-grails-localhost-port

Comment: Thanks Mario.
Your're right about the duplication.
But it's the best regarded answer there, and the docs (setting the ports with system properties in BuildConf.groovy), which are not working here.

Comment: how does `-Dgrails.server.port.http=18080` works out? if it works, you can set the port via the system properties and not via grails at all.

Comment: it is working from command line.But which system properties do you mean? I thought "grails.server.port.http" would be the system property for that?

Comment: you are right, i thought that -Dgrails.server.port.http could be set in a persistent way, but i'm not sure about one. What is your settings   for `grails.serverURL` in `config.groovy`?

Comment: None. As I (also) need https, I didn't know what I should write in grails.serverURL in config.groovy. So I set the ports only in BuildConfig.groovy - but they won't be taken from there - as said